# SQL Server trigger to set default values on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that sets a default value for a column depending on another column whenever a new record is inserted.

Say for example, `room_type` is "Single", then the rent to set to 35,000.

Here's the SQL Server code I'm using to create the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_set_rent
ON room_details
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @type VARCHAR(10)
    SELECT @type = room_details.room_type FROM inserted

    IF @type = 'Single' 
    BEGIN
        SET room_details.monthly_rent = 35000;
    END
    ELSE IF @type = 'Deluxe'
    BEGIN
        SET room_details.monthly_rent =45000;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET room_details.monthly_rent = 25000;
    END
END
```

If anyone has a solution on how to solve the issue with or without using triggers, kindly tell me.

Comment: Please read a tutorial about triggers, Inserted can contain multiple or zero rows, your trigger has to handle that.

Comment: Your trigger has a [common misconception](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) Aside, perhaps you might consider a computed column instead?

Comment: This is usually a bad idea, because things like rates aren't constant. Why not just *set* the value when you do your inserts. Or is this some silly school assignment where logic doesn't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `monthly_rent` is always fixed, you could use a computed column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE room_details
  ADD monthly_rent AS
    CASE type
      WHEN 'Single' 
        THEN 35000
      WHEN 'Deluxe'
        THEN 45000
      ELSE
        25000
      END;
```

You may instead want a small lookup table that you can foreign-key

```sql
CREATE TABLE room_rent (
    type varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    monthly_rent int NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE room_details
  ADD FOREIGN KEY Roomtype_Rent (type)
      REFERENCES room_rent (monthly_rent);
```

If there is an initial amount which can then change, you should ideally do that as part of your `INSERT` procedure.

If you *really, really* need a trigger, you need to take into account multiple (or zero) rows in the `inserted` table, and do a joined `UPDATE` by primary key.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_set_rent
ON room_details
FOR INSERT
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;

UPDATE rd
SET monthly_rent =
    CASE type
      WHEN 'Single' 
        THEN 35000
      WHEN 'Deluxe'
        THEN 45000
      ELSE
        25000
      END
FROM room_details rd
JOIN inserted i ON i.YourPrimaryKey = rd.YourPrimaryKey;
```